# Android studio scrolling listview not working on Lollipop

Tags: android, listview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I recently exported my eclipse project and imported to Android Studio,
and I tried to build and launch it. It works properly all the OS `except Lollipop`.

In Lollipop, all listviews are unable to scroll. Furthermore, items are unselectable even if I touch several times.

So I tried to build with eclipse again and launched it, and guess what? It worked fine again.

Is there any difference between eclipse build and that of studio?

I don't think there are differences on the code and references.

Comment: did u tried different devices ?

Comment: @sush yes I tried Galaxy Note3, Tab4 and G4

Comment: are you exporting gradle build of the project from the eclipse?

Comment: @KaranMer yeah I did use 'Generate gradle build' stuff on eclipse.. is there something wrong with that?

Comment: try upgrading your ADT plugin and gradle plugin from eclipse and gradle plugin from Android Studio, I guess one of the version was having certain bug. Upgrading will surely help because I am able do to this easily.

Comment: @KarenMer k I will try. thx for your reply

Comment: @KarenMer I updated ADT and gradle plugin, but still it has no change.. But I realized that it looks like it scrolls without UI update. I haven't seen such kind of bug and have no idea to solve it.. ;(

Comment: Tesing my project on 4.4.2, Button, ImageView, ListView, RecyclerView are working fine. On 5.1 working Button, ImageView(I can login in my app and replace Fragments), **but ListView and RecyclerView don't working, not scrolling**. compileSdkVersion 23, buildToolsVersion "23.0.2", compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

Comment: upd: on 5.1 "onItemClickListener" working and my app can open another Fragment when I tapped on ListView, I think 5.1 dont update the screen..

Comment: solved a problem: just switch **hardwareAccelerated** in manifest file